# Double indexed sum in sage

Tags: python, sage

I am trying to define the function S(r,s,w) using a double sum in sage. Below is my code

```
def C(m,n,w):
if m>=n:
 return binomial(m,n)

else: 
    return binomial(w-1-m,w-1-n)
k=var('k')
j=var('j')
V=list(var(','.join(['A_%d%d' % (i,n) for i in [0..3] for n in [0..3]])))
def S(r,s,3):
tmp=sum(sum(C(k,r,3)*C(j,s,3)*A_kj, k,0,3),j,0,3)
return tmp
```

I get the error saying that global name A_kj is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your indentation is wrong. Secondly, `A_kj` is not defined because you did not create a object of it. If you add code of where you make an instance of `A_kj` I can help you more.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't understand what you mean by make an instance of A_kj, A_kj's are just variables.

Comment: Where did you type 'A_kj = 0' I understand that it's a variable but I'm asking where did you create the variable

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. In my code a_%d%d suppose to be A_%d%d. I messed it up when I typed the code in the question box. Even so,  I still get the same error message. I think the problem is my list V is not iterable with respect to double indexing.